# Trouble resolving Parameters in Web Forms in 3 tier design

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I have  the following code;

**Student.cs**

```
public class Student
{
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

And my student operations are being done in;

**Students.cs**

```
public class Students
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CodeSampleDb"].ConnectionString;
    public bool AddOrUpdateStudent(Student AcceptedStudent, string ProgramCode)
    {
        bool Success;
        Success = false;

        SqlConnection BAIS3150 = new SqlConnection();
        CodeSample.ConnectionString = connectionString;

        CodeSample.Open();

        SqlCommand AddCommand = new SqlCommand();
        AddCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        AddCommand.Connection = BAIS3150;
        AddCommand.CommandText = "AddOrUpdateStudent";

        SqlParameter AddCommandParameter;

        AddCommandParameter = new SqlParameter();
        AddCommandParameter.ParameterName = "@StudentId";
        AddCommandParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
        AddCommandParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        AddCommandParameter.SqlValue = AcceptedStudent.StudentId;
        AddCommand.Parameters.Add(AddCommandParameter);

        ...............................

        AddCommandParameter = new SqlParameter();
        AddCommandParameter.ParameterName = "@Email";
        AddCommandParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
        AddCommandParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        AddCommandParameter.SqlValue = AcceptedStudent.Email;
        AddCommand.Parameters.Add(AddCommandParameter);

        AddCommandParameter = new SqlParameter();
        AddCommandParameter.ParameterName = "@ProgramCode";
        AddCommandParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
        AddCommandParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        AddCommandParameter.SqlValue = ProgramCode;
        AddCommand.Parameters.Add(AddCommandParameter);

        AddCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        CodeSample.Close();

        Success = true;
        return Success;
    }        
}
```

Then i have a handler which communicates with my UI like this;

**Handler.cs**

```
    public bool EnrolStudent(Student AcceptedStudent, string ProgramCode)
    {
        bool Confirmation;

        Students StudentManager = new Students();

        Confirmation = StudentManager.AddOrUpdateStudent(AcceptedStudent, ProgramCode);

        return Confirmation;
    }
```

And finally i have a web form with code behind in a separate file as below;

**EnrolStudent.aspx**

```
  <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="StudentId" runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox>

    --------------------------------------------------

    <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox>

    <asp:TextBox ID="ProgramCode" runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox>        

    <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Add_Student" />

    <asp:Label ID="Message" runat="server" Text="">
    </asp:Label>
</div>
```

**EnrolStudent.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Add_Student(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool Confirmation;
    CodeSampleHandler RequestDirector = new CodeSampleHandler();
    Confirmation = RequestDirector.EnrolStudent(AcceptedStudent:StudentId.Text, ProgramCode.Text);// I am stuck here, since AcceptStudent is of type Student and this method can only call 2 parameters

    if (Confirmation)
    {
        Message.Text = "Student was added";
    }
    else
    {
        Message.Text = "Student was not added";
    }
}
```

In my code behind class, i am stuck at this line;

`Confirmation = RequestDirector.EnrolStudent(AcceptedStudent:StudentId.Text, ProgramCode.Text);`

I am stuck here, since AcceptStudent is of type Student and EnrolStudent() can only accept 2 parameters, but AcceptStudent is holding an entire Student properties. How do i call parameters in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass Student Object like below. It should work

```
Student objStudent = new Student(); 
objStudent.Email = ""; 
objStudent.FirstName = "";
objStudent.LastName = ""; 
objStudent.StudentId = "";
Confirmation = RequestDirector.EnrolStudent(objStudent, ProgramCode.Text);
```

Comment: This looks promising but, still i was hoping to avoid `Student AcceptedStudent = new Student();` in my UI This should work for now though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you stuck. The first parameter in your function is a Student object. If in the method Add_Student you have a Student object (which i can't see it in your provided code), just pass it into the EnrolStudent method.

Assuming AcceptedStudent is a Student object, your method call would be

```
Confirmation = RequestDirector.EnrolStudent(AcceptedStudent, ProgramCode.Text)
```

Comment: I have tried that, says "The name AcceptedStudent does not exist in the current context". Also note that what i put in that links with the html hence `ProgramCode.Text`. I have to call `AcceptedStudent.StudentId` and `AcceptedStudent.Email`